# why the predict_proba function of sklearn.svm.svc is giving probability greater than 1?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, svc

I've got a **sklearn.svm.svc** (RBF kernel) model trained on two classes containing 140 samples each. The probability is set to true when I tried to predict and the prediction probability of those two classes are varying.

1. For some test samples, it is giving one probability greater than 1
   and other less than one

   e.g ('sample-1': 1.55478334, 'sample-2':
          0.999984).
2. In some cases, it is giving both probabilities less than one

   e.g
       ('sample-1': 0.4182294947776875, 'sample-2':
              0.58177035052223113).

Is my model working well or there is some fault in my training or testing.
[Probability greater then 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exhVq.png)[Probability less then 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIC0D.png)

my code is as follows:

```
#Training code      
        tcdf512_d1=np.empty(280,(18)),dtype=float)
            lables=np.empty((0))
            model512_d1=SVC(probability=True)
            for img,img2 in map(None,catA,catB):
                if img!=None:
                    tcdf512_d1[k]=img(18 features i.e. skewness,variance, standard deviation etc)
                    k+=1
                    lables=np.append(lables,'Cat-VI')
                    pass
                if img2!=None:
                    tcdf512_d1[k]=img2(18 features i.e. skewness,variance, standard deviation etc)
                    k+=1
                    lables=np.append(lables,'Cat-VII')
                    pass
                if k%50==0:
                    print (k)

            print ("LBP Calculated")
            print (time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
            model512_d1.fit(tcdf512_d1,lables)
            tcdf512_d1=None
            lables=None
            k=None
            print ("Model Trained")
            print (time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
            joblib.dump(model512_d1,"Cat/momentsCat_6-7_128_d1.pkl",compress=3)
            print ("Model Saved")
            print (time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
            model512_d1=None
#Testing Code

    size=128
    Cat_I_II       =  joblib.load("Cat/momentsCat_6-7_128_d1.pkl")
    name1="VII"
    print (name1)
    images_address="Catagory/Testbg/"+name1+"/"
    name1="Cat-"+str(name1)
    test_images = cvutils.imlist(images_address)

    count =images_address.rfind("/")+1
    results1=[]
    print (len(test_images))
    print ("Start Time ")
    print (time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
    j=float(len(test_images))
    k=0
#    testdata=[]
    for img3 in test_images:
        results1.append("Image : "+str(img3[count:]))
        results1.append("\n")
    varientarray=[]        
        array=[]
        array.append(img3(18 features i.e. skewness,variance, standard deviation etc))
        print array
        prediction = Cat_I_II.predict(array)[0]
        prob=Cat_I_II.predict_proba(array)[0]
        prob_per_class_dictionary = dict(zip(Cat_I_II.classes_, prob))
        print(prediction,prob_per_class_dictionary)
        results1.append("Result of Cat_I_II is : "+str(prediction) +"\t"+str(prob_per_class_dictionary))
        varientarray.append(prediction)

        print (k)
        print ("Final Result of image "+str(i[count:]) + " is : "+str(collections.Counter(varientarray).most_common(1)[0][0]))
        results1.append("Final Result of image "+str(i[count:]) + " is : "+str(collections.Counter(varientarray).most_common(1)[0][0]))

        if str(i[count:i.index('0')])==collections.Counter(varientarray).most_common(1)[0][0]:
            j-=1
        gc.collect()
        k+=1
    k=float(j*100/len(test_images))
    Accuracy=float((len(test_images)-j)*100/len(test_images))
    print (j)
    print (k)
    print (Accuracy)
    with open("CatResults/_Finalresults.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.write(str("The accuracy for "+str(name1)+" is :"+str(Accuracy)) +"\n")
    results1.append("Incorrect Results are :"+str(j))
    results1.append("The percentage of incorrect result is :"+str(k))
    results1.append("The accuracy is :"+str(Accuracy))
    with open("CatResults/Cat-"+str(name1)+"resultsp2.txt", 'w') as f:
        for s in results1:
            f.write(str(s) +"\n")
    print ("End Time")
    print(time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

My results snippets are as follows

[image: Image Snippet of results]

[image: Results]

Comment: Is that rounding error?

Comment: Please add the actual output for some samples. Dont manipulate it in your wordings. Looks like simple rounding is off. Also please show the code you used. (Right from declaring the SVC to the probability)

Comment: Thanks Kumar for suggesting edits and edits have added and it's not rounding error machine is giving that result and I am confused why please reread the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please notice the `e-06` or `e-08` in those probabilities. Thats equivalent to 10^(-08) in scientific notation. So the above 1 probability you are thinking is very very less.

For example:

```
2.798594e-06 = 0.000002798594
```

Similarly,

```
7.7173288137e-08 = 0.000000077173288137
```

So when you sum those values you will get 1. If not 1, then it will be something like 0.99999999... . Thats expected due to rounding off of the results displayed.

So the `predict_proba` results are not inconsistent. They are actually correct.

Now as for why the predicted result does not match with the highest predicted probability, thats described in the documentation and is expected behaviour  due to internals of the algorithm. Please look at the documentation:-

- http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/svm.html#scores-and-probabilities

> The probability estimates may be inconsistent with the scores, in the
>   sense that the “argmax” of the scores may not be the argmax of the
>   probabilities. (E.g., in binary classification, a sample may be
>   labeled by predict as belonging to a class that has probability <½
>   according to predict_proba.)

Comment: Thanks, Vivek Kumar it sorted out my problem.